# After concatenation 1st letter is not displayed

Tags: c++, concatenation

Below is the code given i have made this program to concatenate two strings concatenation but after concatenation in display it doesnot displays the first word.....i think there is some thing missing in cin.ignore() kindly check and help me????

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#define MAX 100
using namespace std;
void main ()
{

char str[MAX],abc[MAX];
cout<<"\nEnter the string 1";
cin.ignore();                   
cin.get(str,MAX);                                                     
cout<<"\nEnter The String 2";
cin.ignore();
cin.get(abc,MAX);
cout<<"\nS1="<<str;
cout<<"\ns2="<<abc;
strcat(str,abc);
cout<<"\nStrings after catenation are"<<str;
system("pause");

}
```

Errors in this program are that after concatenation first letter is not displayed on this line `cin.ignore();`. Another error is that I want to store result in another char say `char d[MAX]` but compiler gives error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the ".ignore()", which ignores the next character input by the user. Why are you using this?

Comment: Was he trying to grab the newline when the user hit enter? Might be why, but if so he had it out of order. Of course, it's been 15 years since I wrote any C++, so I could be off, but I think that's it.

Comment: but when i dont use cin.ignore it also gives the error thats y i am using this

Comment: @Niazi - Like Eric says, you should use `ignore` to skip the newline *after* a `get`, not before.